# How to get Max and Min IN/OUT time for each date in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, postgresql, linq

I am new to LINQ and have been trying to write a linq query that would be equivalent to the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT linking."RfidNumber",
    linking."VehicleID",
    acs."Date",
    Min(acs."acs_datetime" ) as INTIME,
    Max(acsout."acs_datetime" )  
FROM dbo."acs_transaction_new" acs
INNER JOIN dbo."acs_transaction_new" acsout 
    ON acs."Date" = acsout."Date"  AND acs."acs_operations" = 'in' AND
        acsout."acs_operations" = 'out'
INNER JOIN dbo."PassLinkings" linking ON acs."acs_rfid_no" = linking."RfidNumber" AND
    acs."acs_vehicle_id" = linking."VehicleID"   
WHERE acsout."acs_operations" = 'out' AND acs."acs_operations" = 'in'
GROUP BY linking."RfidNumber", linking."VehicleID",  acs."Date";
```

Basically I want MIN `acs."acs_datetime"` where `acs."acs_operations"='in'`
and similarly MAX `acs."acs_datetime"` where `acs."acs_operations"='out'`
for each date in the table for unique combination of `RfidNumber` and `VehicleID`

**I am lost at Linq:**

```
    var query1 = (from acs in db.acs_transaction
                             join acsout in db.acs_transaction on acs.acs_datetime equals acsout.acs_datetime     
                              join linking in db.PassLinkings on new { rfid = acs.acs_rfid_no, vehicleid = acs.acs_vehicle_id } equals new { rfid = linking.RfidNumber, vehicleid =  (linking.VehicleID == null ? -1 : (int)linking.VehicleID) }
                              where acs.acs_operations == "in" && acsout.acs_operations == "out"
                              select new { acs.acs_rfid_no,
 acs.VehicleID ,
acs."Date",
Min(acs."acs_datetime" ),// something like that
Max(acs."acs_datetime" )
}).ToList(); ;
```

Comment: Try using the method Date (acs.acs_datetime.Date and acsout.acs_datetime.Date) which truncates the hours, minutes, seconds to midnight.

Comment: @jdweng that is not the problem. Problem is I am unable to apply group by and MAX and MIN of datetime column

Comment: Min and Max will be part of the projection for group by

Comment: @MrinalKamboj How do I do it in current scenario?

Comment: `acs."acs_operations"='in' and acsout."acs_operations"='out'` in the actual sql query are these the Where filters post Join

Comment: @MrinalKamboj yes. I have a single column for both in and out time. I can identify which one is in and which one is out time by the value of `acs_operations` column in/off

Comment: A groupby give a two dimensional  array [group,list<object>] so to get the min and max you need to use a Select(x => new { min = x.abc.Min(), max = x.abc.Max()}).ToList()

Comment: Your SQL query was extremely difficult to read because of poor formatting, spacing and capitalization. You will increase your chances to get help significantly if you format your code in a meaningful way. I have done it this time for you for the SQL query. Compare the result with the previous version and you'll know what I mean.

Comment: Check the Edited solution, which has correct version of both Fluent and Query syntax

Comment: I have tested the modified Linq syntax against the Pseudo data models

Answer (score 1):

From the Query that you have posted following is my understanding of your models:

```
public class Acs_Transaction_New_class
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public string acs_operations {get; set;}
    public int acs_rfid_no {get; set;}
    public int acs_vehicle_id {get; set;}
    public DateTime acs_datetime {get; set;}
}

public class PassLinking_Class
{
    public int RfidNumber { get; set; }
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }
}
```

---

### Fluent Syntax:

```
// Data Placeholders to compile linq query

   var result = Acs_Transaction_New
                   .Join(Acs_Transaction_New, acs => acs.Date, acsout => acsout.Date, (acs, acsout) => new { acs, acsout })
                   .Where(x => x.acs.acs_operations == "in" && x.acsout.acs_operations == "out")
                   .Join(PassLinkings, x => new { rfid = x.acs.acs_rfid_no, vehicleid = x.acs.acs_vehicle_id }, linking => new { rfid = linking.RfidNumber, vehicleid = linking.VehicleID}, (x, linking) => new { x.acs, x.acsout,linking })
                   .GroupBy(x => new { x.linking.RfidNumber, x.linking.VehicleID, x.acs.Date })
                   .Select(x => new
                   {
                       x.Key.RfidNumber,
                       x.Key.VehicleID,
                       x.Key.Date,
                       acs_min_datetime = x.Min(y => y.acs.acs_datetime),
                       acs_max_datetime =  x.Max(y => y.acsout.acs_datetime)
                   });
```

### Important Points:

1. Fluent Syntax is much more verbose than Query syntax, but provides a clear data cascading, therefore easier to perceive
2. From the Sql query, I have translated, `acs_operations == "in" / "out"` as Where condition, instead of Join, ideally we don't need comparison with "in" and "out" twice

---

### Query Syntax:

```
var result = from acs in Acs_Transaction_New
             join acsout in Acs_Transaction_New on acs.Date equals acsout.Date
             where acs.acs_operations == "in" && acsout.acs_operations == "out"
             join link in PassLinkings on new { rfid = acs.acs_rfid_no, vehicleid = acs.acs_vehicle_id } equals new { rfid = link.RfidNumber, vehicleid = link.VehicleID}
             group new {acs,acsout } by new { link.RfidNumber, link.VehicleID, acs.Date } into group1
             select new
             {
                 group1.Key.RfidNumber,
                 group1.Key.VehicleID,
                 group1.Key.Date,
                 acs_min_datetime = group1.Min(y => y.acs.acs_datetime),
                 acs_max_datetime = group1.Max(y => y.acsout.acs_datetime)
             };
```

Both versions of the Query are compiling, therefore syntactically correct, you just need to make modifications to suit your use case

Comment: Both queries have the same `where` clause twice?

Comment: I know that's what I can guess from the SQL query, which is joining on the constant value, not sure if that's feasible, `Where` looks like a better choice. It's just an attempt to mimic the exact query, OP needs to modify as per user case

Comment: In case it's a self join then query needs to be modified, but in my view `Where` can serve the purpose better

Comment: True, I see the unnecessary `where` in the SQL query as well, but I think it is better to provide the more correct LINQ.

Comment: Trimmed both formats of the query to remove the extra `Where` clause, integrate the join query with the `PassLinkings` collection. Overall Linq query is now much more compact

Answer (score 0):

Another way (in SQL and LINQ) would be to group the rows regardless of in/out operation, and then filter and min/max inside each group:

```
var ans = from acs in dbo.acs_transaction
          join linking in dbo.PassLinkings on new { RfidNumber = acs.acs_rfid_no, VehicleID = acs.acs_vehicle_id } equals new { linking.RfidNumber, linking.VehicleID }
          group acs by new { linking.RfidNumber, linking.VehicleID, acs.Date } into acsg
          select new {
              acsg.Key.RfidNumber,
              acsg.Key.VehicleID,
              acsg.Key.Date,
              InTime = acsg.Where(acs => acs.acs_operations == "in").Min(acs => acs.acs_datetime),
              OutTime = acsg.Where(acs => acs.acs_operations == "out").Max(acs => acs.acs_datetime)
          };
```

In my LINQ to SQL testing with a similar database query, this generated a single SQL query.